# why after binding grid view the button field become empty field?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xii0L.png)I have a button in gridview to print each row. But after binding using ajax the button become empty.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="VisM_No" HeaderText="Visit No." />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VisM_Date" HeaderText="Visit Date" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Pat_name" HeaderText="Patient Name" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="btnPdf">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" Text="Print PDF" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" CommandName="PrintPDF"/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'button become empty', button is invisible?

Comment: nothing in the cell

Comment: just for testing, remove the css added for template field and for button.

Comment: i try it ,but it's the same

Comment: How do you exactly bind using AJAX? Is the Grid inside an UpdatePanel? If you open the devtool of the browser (F12 key) can you see any Error messages?

Comment: Can you post the entire GridView tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the way the data is bound to the grid.

Here is a working example demonstrating the GridView with AJAX enabled:

```xml
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VisM_No" HeaderText="Visit No." />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VisM_Date" HeaderText="Visit Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pat_name" HeaderText="Patient Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="btnPdf">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" Text="Print PDF" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" CommandName="PrintPDF" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => new {
            VisM_No = x,
            VisM_Date = DateTime.Now,
            Pat_name = "Name " + x

        });
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]